# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when setting SelectedIndex of ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The error says:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '6' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'
>   Parameter name: SelectedIndex

I don't know what that means. This is for my project and this is the first time I try this date onto ComboBox.

```
Private intDaysInMonth(11) As Integer

Private Sub cmbMonth_Click()
    cmbDay.Items.Clear()
    Call PopulateDays()
End Sub

Private Function IsLeapYear(ByVal intYear As Integer) As Boolean
    IsLeapYear = IsDate("29/02/" & intYear)
End Function

Private Sub PopulateDays()
    If cmbMonth.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        If IsLeapYear(cmbYear.Text) Then
            intDaysInMonth(1) = 29
        Else
            intDaysInMonth(1) = 28
        End If
    End If
    For intI = 1 To intDaysInMonth(cmbMonth.SelectedIndex)
        cmbDay.Items.Add(CStr(intI))
    Next intI
End Sub

Private Sub cmbYear_Click()
    Call PopulateDays()
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim intI As Integer
    cmbDay.Items.Clear()
    cmbMonth.Items.Clear()
    cmbYear.Items.Clear()
    For intI = 0 To 11
        intDaysInMonth(intI) = 31
        cmbMonth.Items.Add(Format(CDate("01/" & intI + 1 & "/2011"), "mmmm"))
    Next intI
    intDaysInMonth(1) = 28
    intDaysInMonth(3) = 30
    intDaysInMonth(5) = 30
    intDaysInMonth(8) = 30
    intDaysInMonth(10) = 30
    For intI = 1959 To 2019
        cmbYear.Items.Add(CStr(intI))
    Next intI
    cmbMonth.SelectedIndex = Format(Now, "MM") - 1
    cmbYear.SelectedIndex = Format(Now, "yyyy") - 1959
    cmbDay.SelectedIndex = Format(Now, "dd") - 1
End Sub
```

The expected output must display months/days/years in ComboBox but when the program run it says ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled.

Comment: Is it possible you're setting `cmbDay.SelectedIndex` before it's populated in `PopulateDays`? If `cmbDay` doesn't have anything in it, then a `SelectedIndex` of 6 wouldn't be valid. You could maybe set the `SelectedIndex` in `cmbMonth_Click`. FYI, the click event may not be the best one (e.g. if someone is using keyboard). There's other events like `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` that may be better.

Comment: Also, do you have to use a ComboBox? A DateTimePicker is much better for getting a date from an user.

Comment: Which line throws the error?  DateTime has a static IsLeapYear function built in.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @JeffBridgman, `SelectionChangeCommitted` is raised only when the user makes a selection, so `SelectedIndexChanged` would be required in this case.

Comment: That code looks like it was written in VB6.  There are so many improvements you could make to it in VB.NET.  For instance, formatting part of a `Date` as a `String` is silly when the `Date` has a property for that same part as an `Integer`.  You also seem to be trying to handle a Click event (which is the wrong event to start with) without a `Handles` clause.  I'm guessing that you have copied code of the web with no real understanding of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use a DateTimePicker but if you really must use ComboBoxes the following should work.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillCombo(1959, 61, ComboBox1) 'Year combo
    FillCombo(1, 12, ComboBox2) ' Month combo
End Sub

Private Sub FillCombo(StartNumber As Integer, NumberOfItems As Integer, c As ComboBox)
    'Enumerable.Range(starNumber, number of items)
    Dim items As Integer() = Enumerable.Range(StartNumber, NumberOfItems).ToArray
    Dim strItems As String()
    '.AddRange takes an array of objects and will not covert a value type to a reference type
    'Therefore the conversion to an array of String which is a reference type
    If c.Name = "ComboBox2" Then
        'This is an example of lambda expresions used with Linq
        strItems = items.Select(Function(month) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)).ToArray
    Else
        strItems = items.Select(Function(yr) CStr(yr)).ToArray()
    End If
    c.Items.AddRange(strItems)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim NumberOfDays As Integer
    Select Case ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "September", "April", "June", "November"
            NumberOfDays = 30
        Case "January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"
            NumberOfDays = 31
        Case "February"
            If DateTime.IsLeapYear(CInt(ComboBox1.Text)) Then
                NumberOfDays = 29
            Else
                NumberOfDays = 28
            End If
    End Select
    FillCombo(1, NumberOfDays, ComboBox3)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim dateString = $"{ComboBox2.Text}  {ComboBox3.SelectedItem}, {ComboBox1.Text}"
    Label1.Text = dateString
End Sub
```